Is there a way to deal with factors when graphing a scatterplot matrix?
So was making a scatter plot matrix and noticed that my scatter plots were giving a series of horizontal lines on one side and vertical lines on the other is there a way to make it look like a clump of letters like using the tvalues or something like that? If so how would i accomplish that?
here is my code so far:
CE<-read.csv("Carbon Emission.csv")
CE<-filter(CE, complete.cases(CE))
CE1<-select(CE,ce=CarbonEmission,body_type=Body.Type,sex=Sex, diet=Diet,shower= How.Often.Shower,heat_source=Heating.Energy.Source)

plot(CE1)

Here is what it looks like:


Could we have a [mcve] please? you could look at GGally::ggpairs, which does fancy stuff depending on the types of the two variables involved in any particular panel.

i am sorry i thought i put it with the post
CE<-read.csv("Carbon Emission.csv")
CE<-filter(CE, complete.cases(CE))
CE1<-select(CE,ce=CarbonEmission,body_type=Body.Type,sex=Sex, diet=Diet,shower= How.Often.Shower,heat_source=Heating.Energy.Source)
#CE2<-select(CE,ce=CarbonEmission, trans= Transport, )
#fix CE1
plot(CE1)

That's not a reproducible example since we don't have your CSV file ...

i see my bad  i didn't think of that. hold on i will get something up for that

here focusing on gender on this one:
names <- c("Nguyen", "Murphy", "Rivera", "Cook", "Rogers")
gender <- c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F")
age <- c(29, 28, 38, 48, 31)
bmi <- c(23, 24, 24, 23, 22)
tcl <- c(160, 180, 220, 200, 195)
DF <- data.frame(names, gender, age, bmi, tcl)
DF
plot(DF)

i gues the question should be is there a way to make factors not so factory

When dealing with categorical variables (factors) in a scatterplot matrix, you may see the scatterplots forming horizontal and vertical lines, which indicate the different levels of the factors. If you want to visualize the relationships more clearly, particularly between numeric and categorical variables, you might consider using different visualization techniques.
In R, you can leverage libraries such as GGally, which extends ggplot2 for enhanced scatterplot matrices. Additionally, you can customize the scatterplot matrix to display histograms or bar plots for factors, and scatter plots for numeric pairings.

You might try GGally::ggpairs (slow but fancy). e.g.:
pairs(mtcars)
GGally::ggpairs(mtcars)
## convert variables with few unique values into factors
m2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, 
    function(x) if (length(unique(x)) <= 4) factor(x) else x))
GGally::ggpairs(m2)

